# How to populate NaN values based on conditions from two other columns using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

| ID | hiqual | Wave |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.0 | g |
| 1 | NaN | i |
| 1 | NaN | k |
| 2 | 1.0 | g |
| 2 | NaN | i |
| 2 | NaN | k |
| 3 | 1.0 | g |
| 3 | NaN | i |
| 4 | 5.0 | g |
| 4 | NaN | i |

This is a long format dataframe and I have my `hiqual` variable for my first measurement wave (g). I would like to populate the NaN values for the subsequent measurement waves (i and k) as the same value give in wave g for each ID.

I tried using fillna() but I am not sure how to provide the two conditions of ID and Wave and how to populate based on that. I would be grateful for any help/suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dataframe is already ordered by `ID` and `wave` columns, you can simply fill forward values:

```
>>> df.sort_values(['ID', 'Wave']).ffill()
   ID  hiqual Wave
0   1     1.0    g
1   1     1.0    i
2   1     1.0    k
3   2     1.0    g
4   2     1.0    i
5   2     1.0    k
6   3     1.0    g
7   3     1.0    i
8   4     5.0    g
9   4     5.0    i
```

You can also use explicitly `g` values:

```
g_vals = df[df['Wave']=='g'].set_index('ID')['hiqual']
df['hiqual'] = df['hiqual'].fillna(df['ID'].map(g_vals))
print(df)
print(g_vals)

# Output
   ID  hiqual Wave
0   1     1.0    g
1   1     1.0    i
2   1     1.0    k
3   2     1.0    g
4   2     1.0    i
5   2     1.0    k
6   3     1.0    g
7   3     1.0    i
8   4     5.0    g
9   4     5.0    i

# g_vals
ID
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    5.0
Name: hiqual, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact expected output is unclear, but think you might want:

```
m = df['hiqual'].isna()

df.loc[m, 'hiqual'] = df['Wave'].mask(m).ffill()
```